# Angular 2 Reactive Forms custom validator not setting error type

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I've created a custom validator that combines validation for a date and a time control to check if the (combined) result is in the future or not. That's working flawlessly. However, I can't seem to set the error type in order to check for this particular validation failure using `hasError(...)`.

Here's the validator:

```
export class CustomValidators {
    static isNotInTheFuture(other: AbstractControl, type: string, formatDate: string, formatTime: string) {
        return function (validated) {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                var dateTime: moment.Moment;

                if (type === 'date') {
                    dateTime = moment(other.value + ' ' + validated.value, formatDate + ' ' + formatTime);
                } else if (type === 'time') {
                    dateTime = moment(validated.value + ' ' + other.value, formatDate + ' ' + formatTime);
                } else {
                    reject({ isNotInTheFuture: 'type must be either "date" or "time".' });
                }

                if (dateTime.isAfter(moment())) {
                    resolve({ isNotInTheFuture: false });
                }
                else {
                    resolve(null);
                }
            });
        };
    };
}
```

In my view I got

```
<div class="datepicker md-form-control">
    <md-input readOnly type="text" placeholder="Date" myDatePicker (change)="dateChange($event)" [format]="formatDate" formControlName="date">
    </md-input>
    <small *ngIf="form.controls.date.hasError('isNotInTheFuture')" class="ui error-message" [style.color]="theme.pick('warn')">
        Date is in the future..
    </small>
</div>
```

and here's how I set the control up

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({ 
    ...other controls...
})

let now= moment().toDate();
let date = new FormControl(...initial value...);
let time = ...
...

date.setValidators([
    <any>Validators.required,
    CustomValidators.isNotInTheFuture(time, time, this.formatDate, this.formatTime)
]);

time.setValidators([
    ...
]);

this.form.addControl('date', date);
this.form.addControl('time', time);
```

The problem is, the validation error message is never shown, although I made sure that validation actually fails (couple of `console.log(...)` statements inside the validator).

I then checked the Angular 2 source code and it seems these validation errors for `hasError()` are stored inside the `_errors` property of the control, so I inspected that and there was no error in there either, so that's why `hasError()` defaults to `false`.

My question then is, where did I go wrong?

Comment: I don't think you should `throw` in the validator. Just return an error object instead.

Comment: What Angular2 version are you using?

Comment: RC5 at the moment.

Comment: Likely that this is a bug with async validators.

Comment: Ok, thanks Günter, I'll check the synchronous version then.

Comment: Check, the synchronous version works, so it's probably a bug.